# Itemize - Items order of appeareance

Tags: beamer, lists, overlays

I am using the simple code below to create a list of nested items. I would like to change the order of appearance so that the `enumerate` items, 1 and 2, appear first, and only after that, I would like the other 4 (the `itemize` ones) to appear.
Do you have any suggestions?

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{blabla} \pause
  \begin{enumerate} 
    \item <1-> blabla \pause \\
    \begin{itemize}
      \item blabla \pause
      \item blabla \pause 
    \end{itemize}
    \medskip
    \item <2-> blabla \pause \\
    \begin{itemize}
      \item blabla \pause
      \item blabla
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below I've used `\onslide` to set the appropriate display of items within each list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{blabla}

  \begin{enumerate} 
    \onslide<2->{\item blabla}
    \begin{itemize}
      \onslide<4->{\item blabla}
      \onslide<5->{\item blabla}
    \end{itemize}
    \medskip
    \onslide<3->{\item blabla}
    \begin{itemize}
      \onslide<6->{\item blabla}
      \onslide<7->{\item blabla}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! It works perfectly!